# How to properly deploy a DNN 9

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke-9, dotnetnuke

I'm developing a new internal company portal, and i'm using DNN 9 as a base CMS. Now that i have developed some modules, customize (layouts and icons, no core modifications) DNN to my liking.

How do i deploy DNN application from my dev environment to a production?
Would copy-paste the entire site and backup restore DB work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy-paste/backup-restore would be the simplest approach for deploying your DNN site out to production.

A couple of things to keep in mind.

1) Add the production URLs to the site before you put it in the wild, will make things easier.
2) Once you deploy, you really can't maintain both environments easily. Changes made in one, will NOT be made in another. 
3) If you're making changes to "modules" that you've built, you would typically start packaging and deploying (install/upgrade) those, hopefully you used my VS templates, if so that part is super easy.

You could deploy from DEV to PROD again, but any changes you make in prod will be lost by the process, that's why I say #2 isn't easy.

Answer (score 0):

Chris’ comments are spot on.

You might want to consider using Evotiva’s DNN Backup and Restore product to simplify the process.